# Finding all the JSONS file in directory and combining it in array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, find, command

i wanna find all the json files file specific directory and combine it one parent result that will contain all the result data

I am trying this

```
 find .  -name *data.json | tee result.json
```

It is finding all the data but it is saving its path in result.json,how can i get the data inside all the file and get a combine JSON of all result

this command is saving a **result.json** file which look like this

```
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/17-18/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/18-19/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/10-11/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/11-12/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/15-16/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/19-20/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/14-15/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/12-13/data.json
./17-10-2018/ghatkopar/20-21/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/16-17/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/21-22/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/13-14/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/17-18/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/18-19/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/10-11/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/11-12/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/15-16/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/19-20/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/14-15/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/12-13/data.json
./17-10-2018/mulund-west/20-21/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/16-17/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/21-22/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/13-14/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/17-18/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/18-19/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/10-11/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/11-12/data.json
./17-10-2018/bhandup/15-16/data.json
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want `result.json` to contain; there are many different ways to combine many JSON values into a single value. Do you just want them wrapped in an array?

Comment: yeah,i wanna wrap it in array

Comment: Could you not just save the results from `find` into an array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cat` each file, not output its name. You also need to output a comma before each json except the first one, and the enclosing square brackets:

```
#! /bin/bash
printf [
separator=""
find . -name '*data.json' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r j ; do
    printf $separator
    separator=,
    cat "$j"
done
printf ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will search all data*.json files in current and child folders and combine them as a results.json ( array )

`find . -name data\*.json -type f | xargs cat | sed  -e s/}/},/g -e \$s/,\$/]/ -e 1s/^/[/ > results.json`

I have done basic testing using below commands

`echo {\"name\":\"Alex\", age:24, city:\"Tokyo\"} > sample.json`

`for i in {1..10} ; do cp sample.json data$i.json ; done`

`find . -name data\*.json -type f | xargs cat | sed  -e s/}/},/g -e \$s/,\$/]/ -e 1s/^/[/ > results.json`

If you find its not working for a specific case, I will try to fix it. But as of now it will not work for nested json or json with array.